# Make the div follow the cursor in a live area, and stop following after it leaves it, using percentages

Tags: jquery, html, cursor

I'm new to jQuery, and I'm making a site that is to simulate a credit card being swiped in a card reader, using jquery and **only percentages**. I have most of the site coded, but I can't figure out how to make the **card** div follow the cursor in a certain live area, and not follow when it leaves it.

There is a nice jsFiddle I found that does this, but doesn't work with percentages in the **limitX** or **limitY** of the **var**, only numerical values.

```
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0, limitX = 150-15, limitY = 150-15;
```

here is the jsfiddle for [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fhmkf/)

The working beta I have now works in the sense that the div moves wherever the cursor is, but I want to limit that so **the card doesn't go past the green square**. This is the the current jQuery I have for that.

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
    $('#card').css({
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY
    });
})
```

and here's [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexchopjian/3GVWD/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My teacher helped with this issue. the code is all commented out with details.

What needed to be done was have the limitX variable be **tied to the width** of the container class, rather than specifying a percentage in the jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//Declaring the container size variable when we dom is ready
//Grabbing the size of an element gives a number no longer a percentage
containerWidth = $(".container").width();
containerHeight = $(".container").height();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alexchopjian/5QfYL/5/